# How to save data in database at the time of creation using sequelize in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to save bulk data at the time of database creation. I am having following problems with my code:

- If i keep **models.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function(){ });** then it says table is not created.
- If i keep **{force:false}** then in first deployment it creates table and in second deployment it save data in database.

model/Speclization .js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Speclization = sequelize.define("Speclization",
        {
            speclizationname: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {
            tableName: 'speclization', // this will define the table's name
            timestamps: false           // this will deactivate the timestamp columns
        }
    );

    Speclization.bulkCreate([
        {speclizationname: 'Computer Science'}, // part of records argument
        {speclizationname: 'Information Technology'},
        {speclizationname: 'Electrical'},
        {speclizationname: 'Other'},
        {speclizationname: 'Mechninncal'},
        {speclizationname: 'Electronics'}
    ], ['speclizationname'])
    return Speclization;
};
```

I couldn't figure out that the proper way of how to save data at application deployment in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about removing the `bulkCreate` from the model definition and putting it in the `sync` callback? (because the tables will be created **after** `sync`, so I think you can't `bulkCreate` before `sync` is finished)

Like below:

```
models.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
    Speclization.bulkCreate([
        {speclizationname: 'Computer Science'}, // part of records argument
        {speclizationname: 'Information Technology'},
        {speclizationname: 'Electrical'},
        {speclizationname: 'Other'},
        {speclizationname: 'Mechninncal'},
        {speclizationname: 'Electronics'}
    ]);
});
```

Then having the model definition like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Speclization = sequelize.define("Speclization",
        {
            speclizationname: DataTypes.STRING
        }, {
            tableName: 'speclization', // this will define the table's name
            timestamps: false           // this will deactivate the timestamp columns
        }
    );
    return Speclization;
};
```

Speclization should be written as "Specialization" in English by the way. :)

Comment: can you please tell me how can i recreate database using old database every time it deploy. because if i keep {force: true} then old database is dropped and new is created.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, and I think it belongs in a new question :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right :) . I have posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428355/how-to-recreate-database-from-old-database-using-sequelize-in-node-js