# How to recreate database from old database using sequelize in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am facing some problem with **sequelize** while i keep **{force: true}** . In this case old data dropped and new database is created and my saved data get lost. I want to create new database with old values. Can that possible with **sequelize**  in node.js

Answer (score 2):

When you have database with some data and want to make some changes in db you have two possibilities:

1. as you said recreate db, but this will drop tables (erase your data).
2. use migrations (you can read about it [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/))

Migrations allow you to to don't loose your data and instruct sequelize how to change tables.

There is ticket for recreating tables with alter tables instead of drop tables [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/537)